# Getting the section and address of a label in relation to it's section statically (not at runtime)

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying to get the address of an instruction marked by a label in ARM assembly, in relation to it's section without rewriting an assembler. For example:

```
.text
nop          # 0
mov r1, r2   # 4
loop:
mov r0, #170 # 8
```

If I want the address of `loop` then I get 8, because each instruction here is 4 bytes long and it begins after two instructions.

I have to clarify I'm not looking for `ldr r0, =loop`, I'm looking for a command like GCC which I feed a `.s` file to and get something like

```
loop=.text+0x0000ad4e
abc=.data+0x0000007a
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `objdump -t`?

Comment: Or even the `nm` command?

Comment: @FUZxxl The `nm` command is exactly what I need, Thanks! You can convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either the `nm` or the `objdump -t` command to retrieve the information you are interested in: Before relocation happens, the symbol values printed by `nm` are relative to the segment beginning as you wanted.

The output looks like this:

```
$ nm moves.o
00000000 T attack_map
00000280 T generate_moves
00000160 T gote_in_check
         U moves_for
00000320 T play_move
00000110 T sente_in_check
000001b0 T turn_board
00000000 r turn_board.turned_board
```

and for `objdump -t`:

```
$ objdump -t moves.o

moves.o:     file format elf32-i386-freebsd

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 moves.c
00000000 l     O .rodata    0000001d turn_board.turned_board
00000000 l    d  .rodata    00000000 .rodata
00000000 g     F .text  00000106 attack_map
00000280 g     F .text  00000099 generate_moves
00000160 g     F .text  00000047 gote_in_check
00000000         *UND*  00000000 moves_for
00000320 g     F .text  00000169 play_move
00000110 g     F .text  0000004a sente_in_check
000001b0 g     F .text  000000c7 turn_board
```